# Responsive design issue with div background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why does the background stick out here?

```
.splash {
    width: 100%;
    height: 576px;
    background: url('/static/img/cover.jpg') no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fff;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have specified the `width` to 100%. So the `background-image` takes the whole space.

Comment: If .splash and the menu has the same parent, be sure to change the parent's size to your desire, yet you could 100% the width of the menu.

Comment: Would be good if you provide most of the code or a jfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You set `width: 100%;` that means it displays the full size of the background.

You can specify the exact width you need. And set:

```
max-width: 1000px; //example to set maximum width;
```

So:

```
.splash {
    width: 100%;
    height: 576px;
    max-width: 2000px; //here goes your size
    background: url('/static/img/cover.jpg') no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: What if i want to adjust to the device?

Answer (score 0):

```
.splash img{
width: 100%;
height: 576px;
background-size: cover;
color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to adjust to a device add this inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

and then add this inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<style>
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

and then inside your css you set your width of .splash to 100% it should fill the page on any device.